# CORS response for request with unsupported methods

Tags: rest, http, web, cors

I am wondering how server should respond for CORS request that asks for unsupported method.

I have server endpoint, lets say `server.com/endpoint` which supports only GET. But client is sending CORS OPTIONS request with headers:

```
Origin: another.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
```

How proper response should look? Should it return some error message about unsupported POST method, or just return `200 OK` with typical CORS response  headers like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: another.com
```

Or maybe I should treat it as request without CORS headers?

Also what should be returned in case of some random origin in request? Should i reveal which origins are allowed or keep it hidden and return no "*Allow*" headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am wondering how server should respond for CORS request that asks for unsupported method.
>
> I have server endpoint, lets say `server.com/endpoint` which supports only GET. But client is sending CORS OPTIONS request with headers:
>
> ```
> Origin: another.com
> Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
> ```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests explains what’s happening: That `OPTIONS` is an expected request that browsers on their own automatically send as part of the CORS protocol.

> How proper response should look? Should it return some error message about unsupported POST method

No, supporting the CORS protocol as expected on your server side doesn’t require you to send any special error response for this case. The browser just interprets the lack of "*Allow*" headers in the normal response as meaning that the server doesn’t allow the type of request it’s received.

> or just return `200 OK` with typical CORS response  headers like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: another.com
```

That would be the right way to respond to it as far as supporting CORS as expected for the case where you get a request from the allowed origin `another.com` but for an unsupported method (e.g., `POST`, if you don’t support that). That enables the browser to log a specific CORS error on the client side to let the developer know the non-allowed method is the problem, not the origin.

> Also what should be returned in case of some random origin in request? Should I reveal which origins are allowed or keep it hidden and return no "*Allow*" headers?

You can just return no "*Allow*" headers in the case of a non-allowed origin. There’s never any need to reveal what origins are allowed, except to allowed origins. (Anyway, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value is always just going to contain either a single origin, or else the `*` wildcard, so no random origin making a request is going to be able to sniff out all the allowed origins.)

And to be clear, the CORS protocol in no way requires servers to respond to random non-allowed origins with any CORS headers at all. The semantics of the protocol are such that to a browser, a response with no "*Allow*" headers at all means, *“This server does not allow cross-origin requests from your origin”*. A random non-allowed origin doesn’t need any more information than just that.